# Firebase ML image classification probabilities got a weird output (not in probabilities) ----Update 1

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, image-classification, firebase-machine-learning

I'm new to ML kit Firebase, I'm using the Firebase image classification custom model ML kits.
There have 6 different objects in my custom model
The custom model .tflite file was tested in python and it works perfectly.

print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
0.0 1.0

[  1 224 224   3] <class 'numpy.float32'>
[1 6] <class 'numpy.float32'>

The output should be in probabilities. 
For example:- 0.12,0.54, etc...
But my output has got (Update 1):-
[image]

My reference code:-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models#kotlin+ktx_3

Anybody experience on this issue?

MainActivity.kt (Update 1)

```html
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        title = "Local based image labelling(Free Version)"
        // Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Model download successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val remoteModel = FirebaseCustomRemoteModel.Builder("Gaming4").build()
        val conditions = FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
            .requireWifi()
            .build()

        imageView1.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
        }
        detectButton.setOnClickListener {
            val bitmap: Bitmap = imageView1.drawToBitmap()
            //val image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0) //bitmap format
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Model downloading......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().download(remoteModel, conditions)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Model download successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val options = FirebaseModelInterpreterOptions.Builder(remoteModel).build()
                    val interpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options)
                    val inputOutputOptions = FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                        .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3))
                        .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 6))
                        .build()
                    val Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageView1.drawToBitmap(), 224, 224, true)

                    val batchNum = 0
                    val input = Array(1) { Array(224) { Array(224) { FloatArray(3) } } }
                    for (x in 0..223) {
                        for (y in 0..223) {
                            val pixel = Bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
                            // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                            // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                            // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                            input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel)) / 255.0f
                            input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel)) / 255.0f
                            input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel))/ 255.0f
                        }
                    }
                    val inputs = FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                        .add(input) // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
                        .build()
                    interpreter?.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions)
                        ?.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                            val output = result.getOutput<Array<FloatArray>>(0)
                            val probabilities = output[0]
                            for (i in probabilities.indices) {
                                Log.i("MLKit", String.format("Object : %1.4f", probabilities[i]))
                            }
                        }
                        ?.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Something went wrong. $e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Something went wrong. $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE) {
            imageView1.setImageURI(data?.data)
            detectButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    companion object {
        //image pick code
        private val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000;
    }


}
```

Python : Train model + convert to .tflite (Update 1)
My reference code：-  https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


import pathlib
dataset_url = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/")

data_dir = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/")
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))

print(image_count)

headphone= list(data_dir.glob('Headphone/*'))
keyboard = list(data_dir.glob('Keyboard/*'))
laptop = list(data_dir.glob('Laptops/*'))
monitor = list(data_dir.glob('Monitor/*'))
mouse= list(data_dir.glob('Mouse/*'))
systemunit = list(data_dir.glob('System_Unit/*'))

print(headphone)
print(keyboard)
print(laptop)
print(monitor)
print(mouse)
print(systemunit)


batch_size = 32
img_height = 224
img_width = 224

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")


for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)


normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image)) 


num_classes = 6
model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()



epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)


acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss=history.history['loss']
val_loss=history.history['val_loss']
epochs_range = range(epochs)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()


#Testing Model========================================================================

path = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/Headphone/headphone (26).png/")
path = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/Keyboard/keyboard (26).png/")
path = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/Monitor/monitor (26).png/")
path = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/Mouse/mouse (28).png/")
path = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/Laptop/laptop (26).png/")
path =  os.path.dirname("C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Gaming/System_Unit/systemunit (3).png/")

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)

img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
print(
    "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)


# Convert the model.============================================================
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the same preprocessing in Android as you did in Python.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal which means when I do the standardized data(resize the image) and data augmented(zoom, rotate) in python, I also need to do the same thing in Kotlin??

Comment: I have referred to this link:- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is the .tflite converter was not running well I use another way and the output work perfectly.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

As per the [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#standardize_the_data) mentioned in the comments, the images are normalized to `[ 0 , 1 ]` by dividing each pixel value by 255. This operation is included as a `Layer` in the Keras model,

```
normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
```

Now, in your Java code, you are first subtracting 127.0 and then dividing by 255,

```
input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) -127) / 255.0f
input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) -127) / 255.0f
input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) ) -127/ 255.0f
```

which does not match the normalization performed in the TF tutorial. Hence, the model was not getting the images on which it was trained thereby resulting in wrong predictions.
Make sure you perform the same normalization as in the TF tutorial,

```
input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) / 255.0f
input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) / 255.0f
input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) ) / 255.0f
```

That should solve your problem.

**Tip:**

In most cases, you perform two types of normalization,

```
( pixel_value - 128.0 ) / 128.0
```

Or

```
pixel_value / 255.0
```

The first one squishes the RGB values in `[ -1 , 1 ]` whereas the second one brings them in `[ 0 , 1 ]`.

Comment: Aww, I forget to change it back. In my model normalize is [0,1], it should (Color.red(pixel) / 255.0f.
By the way, even I change it, the output still facing the same problem. Thanks to your reminder